# Do coefficients in moving average process add to 1?

Tags: time-series, moving-average, white-noise

I'm studying weakly stationary stochastic processes, and I'm confused by the title of the "moving average" representation of such a process.

Suppose that $y_t$ is a weakly stationary stochastic process, so that it can be written in the following form: 
$$y_t=\epsilon_t+c_1\epsilon_{t-1}+c_2\epsilon_{t-2}+...$$

where the epsilons are following a white noise distribution. This is supposedly referred to as the MA($\infty$) representation of a weakly stochastic process, but because it is referred to as a moving *average*, I am inclined to interpret the $c$ coefficients as being weights, in which case I believe they should add up to one. Is this correct?

Comment: No, they do not add to one. The term is simply misleading.

Comment: Because the (common) variance $\sigma^2$ of the $\epsilon_t$ is unspecified, the sum of the coefficients (including the initial $1$) has no meaning.  Without any loss of generality, then, the sum could be constrained to be in the set $\{0,1,-1\}$ through a suitable choice of $\sigma.$  This slightly generalizes the sum-to-unity ("average") case.  Thus, maybe the terminology is not that misleading.